# How to change the config file of the VM in VMware Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I move the VM's files(contains the `Controller1_42.120.vmx`) to the `E:\VMs\Controller1\` directory.

but when I restart my VM(`Controller1_42.120`) it will get failure because the VMware Workstation think the Config file(`Controller1_42.120.vmx`) still in the old position, but I have moved it, so how can I change the configuration in the VMware Workstation?

At the below image I can not change it:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Someone know how to change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The filename is `Controller1_42.120.vmx`, not `...vmxl`.  Are you confusing the *cursor* for the letter `l`?
2. If you have the VM open in VMware Workstation and move the file, then that won't work; VMware Workstation won't expect the file to be moved around while it's still in use!  You need to close the VM, move the file, and then reopen it (e.g. via File > Open or by double-clicking on the `.vmx` file).